# Infinite loop (Html) Hide and unhide a text after 1 seconds (Html)

Tags: html, time, hide

Hi i have created this script to hide and show a text after 1 seconds, But I want that the text must be shown for a single second and must remain hidden for 6 seconds so on to the infinity that never stops
, how I can create this kind of HTML script?

```html
<h1 style="text-align: left;" id="xhide">Hello World</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=true;
function hide(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id);
    d.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
}

function show(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id)
    d.setAttribute('style','display:block;')
}
  
setInterval(function() {
    if(flag) {
        show('xhide');
        flag=false;
    } else {
       hide('xhide');
       flag=true;
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to show for one second and then hide for one second? and then show 2 seconds and hide 2 seconds and so on? Or do you want to show for 1 second and then hide 6 seconds and then show 1 and hide 6 over and over?

Comment: I want only to show the text for 1 second and then hide for 6 seconds in a infinite loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and unhide a text after 6 seconds in a infinite loop (Html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392480/hide-and-unhide-a-text-after-6-seconds-in-a-infinite-loop-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement count instead of simple flag like below

```
<h1 style="text-align: left;" id="xhide">Hello World</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=0;
function hide(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id);
    d.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
}

function show(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id)
    d.setAttribute('style','display:block;')
}

setInterval(function() {
    if(flag==6) {
        show('xhide');
        flag = 0 ;
    } else {
       hide('xhide');
       flag++;
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```