# Hide and unhide a text for 6 seconds with a loop only for two times (Html)

Tags: text, hide, setinterval, getelementbyid

Hi i have created this script to show a text for 1 second and after to hide the same text for 6 seconds in a loop that never ends , but I want that the text should remain hidden for the first six seconds and then after must be displayed for one single second, and now without a endless loop and for only twice , how I can create this kind of html script?

```html
<h1 style="text-align: left;" id="xhide">Hello World</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=0;
function hide(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id);
    d.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
}

function show(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id)
    d.setAttribute('style','display:block;')
}

setInterval(function() {
    if(flag==6) {
        show('xhide');
        flag = 0 ;
    } else {
       hide('xhide');
       flag++;
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Someone Can help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and unhide a text after 6 seconds in a infinite loop (Html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392480/hide-and-unhide-a-text-after-6-seconds-in-a-infinite-loop-html)